# EclipseLink SQLServerException when returning stored procedure without result set

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink 2.4.2 to call a stored procedure in a SQL Server database. The stored procedure is legacy code where I have no insight.

```
StoredProcedureCall call = new StoredProcedureCall();
call.setProcedureName("p_get_sales");
call.addNamedArgument("p_part", "part")
call.addNamedArgument("p_product_nr", "productNr")
call.addNamedArgument("p_lang", "lang")

DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery(call);
query.addArgument("part")
query.addArgument("productNr")
query.addArgument("lang");

JpaEntityManager jpaem = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class);
List<ArrayRecord> records = (List<ArrayRecord>) jpaem.getActiveSession().executeQuery(query, Arrays.asList(part, productNr, lang));
```

All is fine if data is available so that a result set is returned by the procedure. Sometimes there does not exist any data in the database to be returned. In this case I get the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
Error Code: 0
Call: EXECUTE p_get_sales @p_part = ?, @p_product_nr = ?, @p_lang = ?
    bind => [Total, 5, de]
Query: DataReadQuery()
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1589)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1554)
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:408)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:609)
    ... 47 more
```

What do I have to do to avoid the exception in case there is no result set returned?

Comment: try and catch sounds familiar?

Answer (score 0):

try and catch?

```
List<ArrayRecord> records;
try{
List<ArrayRecord> records = (List<ArrayRecord>) jpaem.getActiveSession().executeQuery(query, Arrays.asList(part, productNr, lang));
}catch(DatabaseException ex){
 records = new ArrayList<ArrayRecord>();
return records; //RETURN EMPTY LIST, OR YOU CAN HANDLE YOUR OWN EXCEPTION
}
```

It is a specific driver Exception, so you must handle it yourself (it is not a common empty resultset).

If your query doesn't execute SELECT operation, but executes either INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation, then use `executUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`, therefore preventing the driver exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I could use try/catch but it seems more like a workaround than a solution. I would like to avoid the exception being thrown.

Comment: I just read your last sentence. You say this is expected behavior by the sqljdbc4 driver?

Comment: Ah! yes, missed that completely. If your query doesn't execute SELECT operation, but executes either INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation, then use executUpdate instead of executeQuery.

Comment: By using executeUpdate you will prevent the driver exception.

Comment: No I do not need executeUpdate because this is not DML operation. The SP fetches data (if available) and returns it.

Comment: Well, then you need to handle the exception. That's a driver exception than might involve getting into the SP design (which you don't have access) in order to assess any cursor usage.